# Need Two views on a single page with separate modules in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          var moduleA = angular.module("MyModuleA", []);
          moduleA.controller("MyControllerA", function($scope) {
              $scope.name = "Azhar";
          });

          var moduleB = angular.module("MyModuleB", []);
          moduleB.controller("MyControllerB", function($scope) {
              $scope.name = "Khan";
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="AgeCalc">
            <h1>Age Calculator</h1>
            <div ng-app="MyModuleA" ng-controller="MyControllerA">
                {{name}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Currency Converter">
            <h1>Currncy Converter</h1>
            <div ng-app="MyModuleB" ng-controller="MyControllerB">
                {{name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
       
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="App1" ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="MyControllerA">
        <h1>My Name</h1>
        <div >
            <span>{{name}}</span>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="App2" ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="MyControllerB">
        <h1>My Surname</h1>
        <div >
            <p>{{name}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
            angular.module("myApp1", [])
            .controller("MyControllerA",
                function($scope) {
                    $scope.name="sagar";
                   
                }
            );
            angular.module("myApp2", [])
            .controller("MyControllerB",
                function($scope) {
                    $scope.name = "chopada";
                }
            );
            angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"),['myApp2']);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope It Will Help You...

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually bootstrap the Angular apps as below. Check out the link: https://plnkr.co/edit/iW8GzBgexjylXiq1IWtp?p=preview

```
    <div id="AgeCalc">
        <h1>Age Calculator</h1>
        <div ng-app="MyModuleA" ng-controller="MyControllerA">
            {{name}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Currency Converter">
        <h1>Currncy Converter</h1>
        <div ng-app="MyModuleB" ng-controller="MyControllerB">
            {{name}}
        </div>
    </div>

    var moduleA = angular.module("MyModuleA", []); 
moduleA.controller("MyControllerA", function($scope) { $scope.name = "Azhar"; });

var moduleB = angular.module("MyModuleB", []);
moduleB.controller("MyControllerB", function($scope) { $scope.name = "Khan";});
 angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyModuleA','MyModuleB']);
    });
```